# How can I make a formula reset/recalculate itself throughout a worksheet as a new subset of data begins?

Tags: excel

I have a set of data that is large 20K rows or so, and I have a simple task, but I am not sure as to the best way to automate the ask.

For the sake of the example we have

| Unit | Quantity | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| % | 10 | 10% |
| % | 50 | 50% |
| LB | 100 |  |
| LB | 50 |  |
| % | 20 | 20% |
| % | 20 | 20% |
| LB | 10 |  |

Clarification (actual example)

| A (Component) | B (Unit of Measure) | C (Quantity) | D (Result) - Note A123 and B456 are calculated as their own percentage of total when unit =% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123 | % | 50 | 50 of 100 expressed as .5000 |
| A123 | % | 25 | 25 of 100 expressed as .2500 |
| A123 | LB | 50 | 50 (since unit <> % result just carries over) |
| A123 | LB | 50 | 50 (since unit <> % result just carries over) |
| A123 | % | 25 | 25 of 100 expressed as .2500 |
| B456 | % | 100 | 100 of 200 expressed as .5000 |
| B456 | LB | 50 | 50 (since unit <> % result just carries over) |
| B456 | LB | 50 | 50 (since unit <> % result just carries over) |
| B456 | % | 75 | 75 of 200 Expressed as .3750 |
| B456 | % | 25 | 25 of 200 Expressed as .1250 |

What I am looking to do is two fold

1 - Create a formula that calculates the total percentage of the quantity, but only if the Unit Type is %. If this needs to be done across multiple columns and formulas it's okay as the results will be migrated to their own sheet.
2 - have the formula reset throughout the spreadsheet to account for each new subset of data. So the data is a series of makeups of components. So the table above is theoretically in the same documents 1000s of times, but the number of rows varies. The only constant is the need for the % of  the respective quantity for that component.

(C) Quantity is always expressed as the total units used. However when B(Unit of measure) is listed I need to determine what percentage of that unit accounts for the actual total quantity (only for those for which % is listed). Those in LBs are okay in their current state.

The component is the divider and when the component changes the need to recalculate the respective percentages does as well.

Hope this makes more sense

There are some consistencies in terms of labels for the components if there is a way to create subsets via if statements or something.

Happy to provide any additional clarification.

Thank you

**(What I've tried so far)**

right now it's kind of a mess. I have multiple helper columns built off to the side.

in order

1. is an if statement that confirms if the Unit is a % or LB. % returns 1 and LB returns 0
2. If that helper column is a 1 (%) the next column brings over the quantity. If not it's blank. I then subtotal the returned results
3. The next column divides that row by the subtotal returning the overall percentage of
4. final column then uses an if statement. If the first helper column is 1(%) then bring over the result, otherwise the original quanity

Comment: What have you tried? For the first line in your example, `10` is `10%` of what?

Comment: I'm currently working on a potential solve, but thought process is to create an IF statement that determines if the component matches. So IF neighboring names=one another 1,2. Then I can set it up so that if the component number is the same then apply the formula to those matching cells.


10% is the percent of which ten is amongst all quantity which is measured in %. So 10+ 50+20+20 = 100. 10 is 10% of that calculated 100.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68898910/edit) to add details, include the specific formulas you have tried ans a clear explanation of how they fail to achieve what you want. As it is, you assume everyone knows what you know about these numbers, which is not the case.

Comment: Ok will do. I feel like in the past I have done that an ended up getting people lost in the details.

Comment: updated description - please let me know if anything unclear

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution:

```
=IF(B2="%",C2/SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,A2,B:B,B2),C2)
```

If you want the result to actually look like a percentage, you can use conditional formating with the following condition:

```
=B2="%"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Looking it over now. I think this might have done the trick, appears to be flawless so far. Just keeping it from being solved for the moment in case they have any unforseen revisions.